# TSQL While Looping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Server table and have elapseddays and enddate columns.  What I want to do is to loop through the table and find out if the enddate is less than the system date. If so then the difference is the no of days elapsed. Then I will update the elapseddays column with that no of days. The elapseddays column is numeric. Below is the tsql code:

```
WHILE (SELECT EndDate FROM LiftingSummary) < GETDATE()
BEGIN
        UPDATE LiftingSummary
        SET ElapsedDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), EndDate)
END
```

If I run the code I get the following error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Am desperate and don't know what to do.  I need help please.  Thank you.

Comment: Stop thinking about looping. You are thinking "I need to do x to each of these rows" and you should be thinking "I need to do x to this set of rows." Why not just `UPDATE dbo.LiftingSummary SET ... WHERE EndDate < GETDATE();`? This will update all of the rows at once instead of one at a time. By using a loop you are essentially driving to the grocery store, buying bread, driving it home, then driving back to the grocery store, buying milk, driving it home, then driving back to the grocery store, buying eggs...

Comment: May be like you're saying, you're right.  I think my difficulty here is getting the difference between the EndDate and GETDATE() and using that to update ElapsedDays Column.

Comment: Well I think you just have it backwards. You say "enddate is less than the system date" but `DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), EndDate)` for those rows would return a negative number. Try `DATEDIFF(DAY, EndDate, GETDATE())`. But also, why are you storing "ElapsedDays" in the table? That number becomes obsolete at midnight tonight. If the fact that the elapsed days were calculated on October 23rd is important, then you need another column to indicate that date. Generally, though, you should avoid storing redundant data in the table and just calculate it at runtime.

Comment: Aaron, is it possible to put the result of the SELECT DATEDIFF in a variable and use later?  When I run the query the following is the error message I get: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The reason you have a problem is that you expect "the result" to be a single value. If you have two rows that have EndDate < today, which one is "the result"? Aren't you trying to update the table? If you have a single UPDATE statement that updates *all* of the relevant rows in one pass, what are you going to do with that variable later? And again, which affected row should the variable represent? First? Last? Latest? Earliest? Random?

Comment: Aaron, my problem is how can I update all the rows that meet the condition, that is EndDate being less than GETDATE

Comment: We've told you multiple times how to update all the rows that meet the condition.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be looping
But, breaking down the error message

```
WHILE (SELECT EndDate FROM LiftingSummary) < GETDATE()
```

That select can return more than one row and I suspect it is
That is exactly what that error message is telling you

Is this what you mean to do?

```
UPDATE LiftingSummary
SET ElapsedDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, EndDate, GETDATE())
WHERE EndDate < GetDate()
```

Comment: Yes, Frisbee.  So how can I go through the table and update all the rows that meet the condition, that is EndDate being less that GETDATE

Comment: @Bainn Again, you are thinking too hard about **each row** that meets that condition. The last `UPDATE` statement in this answer will update **all of the rows** that meet that condition.

Comment: @Bainn *You* don't need to go through the table and do it. The `UPDATE` statement already operates on all the rows meeting the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Frisbee, honestly, may be C# foreach statement clouded my thinking. Your code above has worked just that.  Like Aaron said, I didn't need any looping.  Folks, thank you very much indeed.